# Building correct array in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

Im building against an API that has dummy data for me to follow(Yay).
Arrays are pretty basic, but im stuck. the api will eat the dummy data perfectly, but not my dynamically made array.

Heres the dummyarray:

```
   array(
        'Name'=> 'Testing Recipient1',
        'Email'=> 'test@test.no',
        'MobileNumber'=> '32323232',
        // 'SSN'=> '00000000000',
        'Priority'=> 0
  ),
    array(
        'Name'=> 'Test Test',
        'Email'=> 'Test@test2.no',
        'MobileNumber'=> '32323232',
        // 'SSN'=> '00000000000',
        'Priority'=> 0
    )
);
```

So i go right ahead and do this:

```
$recipients2 = array();
foreach($signants as $signant) {
    $name = $signant['signame'];
    $email = $signant['signmail'];
    $signarr = array(
        "Name" => $name,
        "Email" => $email,
        "MobileNumber" =>'32323232',
        "Priority"=>'0'
    );
    array_push($recipients2, $signarr);
}
```

The output of that is:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => test test
            [Email] => test@test2.no
            [MobileNumber] => 32323232
            [Priority] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => test test
            [Email] => test@gmail.com
            [MobileNumber] => 32323232
            [Priority] => 0
        )

)
```

What in NULLS name am i doing wrong?

Comment: Since we don't know anything about the API, nor have you givenany details or error messages, nobody can help here.

Comment: Well, the API does not really matter. the dummy array is all i need to replicate, and my approach is appearantly not doing that. The error 
messages back from the api would not tell you anything.

Comment: The only difference I see, you have a duplicate name in the dynamic array. Although, this should be mentioned in an error message.

Comment: @Havihavi Also, words in `Name` and `Email` are capitalized, that differs as well. So basically you're asking "What differs between these two arrays?" ?

Comment: did you do a `var_dump()` on the dummy array, and compare with your real one?  also, your API may accept JSON only instead of an array.  Just a thought.

Comment: it was the capitals in names. djiz, thats strict!  Thanks for taking the time to  look into this with me =)